# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\cos x+1)$ does not exist?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I'm struggling with this task:

> Prove that
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\cos x+1)$$
> does not exist.

I don't know which claims I should use...

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean for a limit to not exist? What have you tried,

Answer (score 2):

Take the sequence $\{(2n+1)\pi\}$ and the sequence $\{2n\pi\}$.  Then both these sequence tend to infinity but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\cos((2n+1)\pi)\bigg)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\cos(2n\pi)\bigg)=2$ . This proves that the limit cannot be unique and hence the limit cannot exist.

Comment: [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions like these where OP has not shown any work.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on why Mr.Gandalf Sauron's answer works, you can prove that the limit exists if any only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\cos(x_n))$$

converges to the same limit for **any** choice of sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the domain such that $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. This means that to prove the limit does not exist, simply find two sequences for which you get different limit, or find a sequence where the limit does not even exist, both methods work, and are great general approaches for proving limits do not exist.

Comment: [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)